# how to show wordpress site title and tagline?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to put site title and tagline in child theme header. I searched about it and find these two different wordpress functions [get_bloginfo()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) and [bloginfo()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/).

`get_bloginfo()` doesn't showing the tagline, and `bloginfo()` showing both site title and tagline. Problem is that `bloginfo()` is removing the `:` and space between site title and description.

```
<title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' : '. bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></title>
```

**Title:** WebsiteThis is example website.

You can see there is no space between `Website` and `This`.

So is this possible that i show the site title and tagline with properly space and `:`?

Comment: You can use `wp_title();`

Comment: @KaushaMehta `wp_title` is for displaying the page title, not the site title.

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
<title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' : '. get_bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></title>

echo get_option('blogname'); // For Site Name
echo get_option('blogdescription'); // For Tag line or description
```

Answer (score 16):

This will help you.

```html
<title> 
<?php
 $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
 $site_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    //for home page
 if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ):
  echo $site_name;echo ' | '; echo  $site_description; 
 endif;
 // for other post pages
 if (!( is_home() ) && ! is_404() ):
 the_title(); echo ' | '; echo $site_name;
 endif;
 ?>
</title>
```